# VPS hosting with IP failover across datacenters

Tags: vps, failover, high-availability

Is there any VPS hosting that would allow IP failover (or remapping) across different datacenters ? The only one I aware of is EC2 with their Elastic IP.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have servers in two separate datacenters and when one server or one datacenter fails, it would fail-over to the second server.

Managing BGP on my own is out of question. DNS seems to be not a perfect solution because of propagation delays.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a VPS that offered that kind of feature.  Your best bet would be either using DNS with a low TTL or using AWS with an EIP.

You could even use AWS AutoScaling and a start-up script in your AMI to self-heal from failures.